# Trouble summing an array in vanilla Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm having trouble summing an array. Here's my existing code:

```
pageArray = Array.new
puts "How many pages long is the book you're reading?"
pageArray << gets.chomp
puts "Are you reading any other books right now?"
yn = gets.chomp
while yn != "no" do    
  puts "How many pages long is your next book?"  
  pageArray << gets.chomp
  puts "Are you reading any other books right now?"
  yn = gets.chomp
end
pageSum = pageArray.reduce(:+)
puts pageSum
```

When I go through and enter the values 100 and 50, the final return is "10050," rather than "150." Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: yes.  you are pushing strings into your array, so the + operating is  doing a concatenation not integer addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code could be written more clearly, and more Ruby-like. Here's some untested code that is more idiomatic:

```
page_array = []

puts "How many pages long is the book you're reading?"
page_array << gets.chomp

loop do
  puts 'Are you reading any other books right now?'
  yn = gets.chomp.downcase
  break if yn == 'no'

  puts 'How many pages long is your next book?'  
  page_array << gets.chomp.to_i
end

page_sum = page_array.reduce(:+)
puts page_sum
```

Notice:

- variables in Ruby are in snake_case, notInCamelCase.
- `loop do` will loop forever. Simply `break` when you've received the break value.
- you should fold the case of the value used as a break to catch variations in 'y' and 'Y'.
- take the time to format your code so it's easily read, even for quick tests. It's amazing how often code we think is just a test actually gets put into production, so do it right the first time.

Comment: Sn, I just posted a near carbon-copy of your answer, then took it down when I saw yours.  The only differences were that I put mine in a method (`puts total_pages()`), didn't have the variable `yn` (`break if gets..`) and had just `gets.to_i`. Toof, in real life you'd also what to put all `gets` in loops and test for validity.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I figured it was something fairly simple. The formatting broke on copy-paste from Sublime Text, I'm guessing that's something to do with my lack of familiarity.

Comment: In order to get your snippet to work, though, I had to change `page_array << gets.chomp` to `page_array << gets.chomp.to_i` - does that sound right?

Comment: Possibly. I modeled the code after your own code so if yours was wrong that would have been passed on. As I said, it was untested.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering strings and concatenating them.

Use `gets.chomp.to_i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the string you get from `gets` to an int.

`pageArray << gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: `chomp` is optional here, because "123followed by any string of characters--including just an end-of-line character--sent the method 'to_i' returns an integer derived from the digits at the beginning of the string".to_i => 123`.